# Installing traffic control on a docker container

Tags: docker, redhat, rhel, rhel8, iproute

I'm trying to use traffic control (`tc`) in my docker container. However it does not find it.

I have installed iproute with yum

```
yum install iproute -y
```

I thought it should include traffic control (tc) commands. However it does not. I thought maybe it is in a different package (as it was suggested here and there). But none of these work:

> ```
> yum install iproute -y
> yum install iproute-tc -y
> yum install iproute2 -y
> yum install tc -y
> ```

My disto:

```
# cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.9 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.9"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.9 (Ootpa)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8::baseos"
```

Ultimately I want to use the docker image as a stub where I can send traffic too and respond with delays (to do small scale load/stress testing). Traffic control is a powerfull tool to artifically create latency.

Comment: Could you please share the __full__ terminal output of "does not find it"?

Comment: I get:
Last metadata expiration check: 1:46:15 ago on Mon Feb  5 17:06:04 2024.
No match for argument: tc
Error: Unable to find a match: tc

Answer (score -1):

I tried to get this to work using the UBI Red hat image but was not successful.

However, it works with a Fedora base image, which is essentially Red Hat.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM fedora:40

RUN dnf update -y && dnf install -y iproute-tc
```

Build and run.

```
docker build -t fedora-tc .
docker run -it fedora-tc
```

[image]

Comment: I hoped the update command would help, but same result. I could indeed make a new image, but I hoped to be able to use the current one. I need apache zookeeper to run on it, so I used the default zookeeper docker image.

Comment: So the problem is solved then? Great. However, I think that my answer addresses the original question (where the constraint on Zookeeper was not mentioned). For the purpose of other folk who end up on this page, can you please either accept my answer or let me know what still needs to be done to handle the original problem.